# injecting service into controller using Unity

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, wcf, unity-container

I'm injecting a wcf service into a controller using Unity. However I've noticed there's no way to close the service. How can I make sure the connection to the service gets closed after the service method returns ?

```
public ITiers TierClient { get; set; }

    public HomeController(ITiers tierClient)
    {
        TierClient = tierClient;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";

        bool result = TierClient.CheckIfTierExiste("***", "***", null, true);


        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [`custom lifetime manager`](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/introducing-the-unity.mvc3-nuget-package-to-reconcile-mvc3-unity-and-idisposable) for this dependency. I would recommend you using the [`Unity.MVC3`](http://unitymvc3.codeplex.com/) NuGet package which registers a custom dependency resolver and this custom lifetime manager allowing you to handle `IDisposable` resources.

Comment: thanks, I've added the HierarchicalLifetimeManager to my container. Is it a problem if the interface of my service does not contain the Close() method ? Would the service still be closed ?

Comment: There's no `Close` method in the `IDisposable` interface. You should have a `Dispose` method on your concrete type.